# spectrogram for one x-axis accelerometer signal

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, accelerometer, spectrogram

trying to convert accelerometer signal into spectrogram instead of raw data
i try the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np 
sample_rate, samples = np.loadtxt("trainingdataset.txt", delimiter=",", dtype=np.int32)

frequencies, times, spectogram = signal.spectrogram(samples, sample_rate)

plt.imshow(spectogram)
plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, spectogram)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

but it gets me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hadeer.elziaat/Desktop/r.py", line 5, in <module>
    sample_rate, samples = np.loadtxt("trainingdataset.txt", delimiter=",", dtype=np.int32)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

the dataset text file only contains the accelerometer x-axis with 2947 rows and one column

this is my dataset

```
150
100
100
100
100
```

Comment: show your .txt-

Comment: done .. i have add a sample of my dataset

Comment: If you want to do a spectrogram you need the time intervals in which the sample was taken, you only provide the value of the sample with which it is impossible.

Comment: is the time interval will be added in the dataset or in the code?